# Accessing the RDS snapshot_arn in an Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook that given an RDS snapshot NAME, needs to get the ARN for that snapshot:

```
- name: get snapshot information
  rds_snapshot_info:
    db_snapshot_identifier: "{{ source_name }}"
  register: source_snapshot_facts

- name: display some stuff
  debug:
    msg: The snapshot name is {{ source_name }} and it has an ARN of "{{source_snapshot_facts.snapshots}}"
```

gives me:

`TASK [display some stuff] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** ok: [localhost] => { "msg": "The snapshot name is rds:client-p-qcpdb-rds-use-2023-07-26-07-15 and it has an ARN of \"[{'db_snapshot_identifier': 'rds:client-p-qcpdb-rds-use-2023-07-26-07-15', 'db_instance_identifier': 'client-p-qcpdb-rds-use', 'snapshot_create_time': '2023-07-26T07:15:56.130000+00:00', 'engine': '  <snip> 'db_snapshot_arn': 'arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:##########:snapshot:rds:client-p-qcpdb-rds-use-2023-07-26-07-15',... <SNIP>...'}}]\"" }`
`

I can't figure out how to properly reference that 'db_snapshot_arn' item however ...

"{{source_snapshot_facts.snapshots.db_snapshot_arn}}" is invalid .. as is "{{source_snapshot_facts.snapshots['db_snapshot_arn']}}"

This is probably something silly due to my lack of python/ansible knowledge, but any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [0] in a debug message for refers to the first element of a list or an array. It is used to access a specific item within a list variable or array and print value.

```
- name: get snapshot information
  rds_snapshot_info:
    db_snapshot_identifier: "{{ source_name }}"
  register: source_snapshot_facts

- name: display some stuff
  debug:
    msg: The snapshot name is "{{ source_name }}" and it has an ARN of "{{source_snapshot_facts.snapshots[0].db_snapshot_arn}}"
```

It's working for me.